# Why this for loop starts from half and not prints out every thing?

Tags: c

I am learning C , I have written one C program which asks the user to enter a starting number and ending number , and it prints out the number stating from starting number to ending number . For example , if a user enters 5 as the starting number and 10 as the ending number , it prints out 5 6 7 8 9 10 . Here is the code : -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int start ;
    int end ;
    int counter ;

    // Asking the starting number
    printf("Enter the starting number : ") ;
    scanf("%d" , &start) ;

    // Asking the last number
    printf("Enter the last number : ") ;
    scanf("%d" , &end) ;

    for (counter = start ; counter <= end ; counter++)
    {
        printf("%d\n" , counter) ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code runs perfectly for small gap numbers (like 5 to 10 , 1000 to 1025) , But whenever I type the large gap numbers like 100 to 500 , It prints out the numbers starting from 205 to 500 , Even I scroll up I can't find the numbers from 100 to 204 . I am using  [Code::Blocks (version 13.12)](http://www.codeblocks.org/) . Can anybody figure it out whats wrong with this code ? Thanks :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. In fact the complete out put you are getting doesn't fit in the window and gets deleted. See the output here: http://ideone.com/rentSf

Comment: That must be limitiation of scrolling. You could just scroll upto 'x' lines. if you want to see output, redirect the output to a file.

Comment: It works perfectly no error! See - http://ideone.com/cwyk74, you didn't check the output properly!

Comment: @NicolusBuck: When the terminal window comes, in front of you. Right Click on the top bar of Console, select __Properties->Layout Tab__. Then set __Screen Buffer Size: Height = 500__, that is it. Click `OK`. Now enter `100` as starting value and `500` for ending value. Scroll up to see all values :-)

Answer (score 4):

Command line display has a limited history. You are printing a large amount of numbers old lines get removed.

Print you numbers into a file using fopen() and fprintf(), so you can inspect them all.

Comment: @NicolusBuck http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+fopen+fprintf or google their names.

Answer (score 3):

As everybody has mentioned, your command line history has run out of its limit and hence, you cannot *scroll back* to the starting point. So, you're missing out the complete output.

Assuming you're on linux, run your executable like

> ./a.out > test1.txt

and then open and check the newly created file using `vi`

> vim test1.txt

Hope you'll get the complete o/p.

Comment: He has already mentioned that he is using an IDE: Code::Blocks.

Comment: @haccks . Right. I overlooked that part. :-(

Comment: Sorry , I am on Windows 8.1 not on linux , But I love Ubuntu :)

Comment: @ NicolusBuck yeah. then you need to use a file for writing the o/p, as @2501 has mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it a bit easier on yourself by printing the numbers out in sequence without newlines to confirm. That will eliminate the scrolling issue:

```
for (counter = start ; counter <= end ; counter++)
{
    printf(" %d" , counter) ;
}
printf ("\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a space in your `printf()` instead of newline character `'\n'` like

```
printf("%d " , counter) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program will print the whole sequence, just that you are not able to see it.
Try writing the output in a file and then you will be able to see the whole output.
This thing is happening because console has a limited capacity, otherwise your code will run perfectly fine.